# Where are Microsoft.Samples.DirectX.UtilityToolkit for Managed DirectX?

Tags: user-interface, directx, sample

I found this page speaking about DirectX user control:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb153289(v=vs.85).aspx

I download several DirectX SDK and the code should be here but I can't find it:

*(SDK root)\Samples\Managed\Direct3D\CustomUI*

Does someone have an idea where I can download these samples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found in [DirectX SDK april 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=86cf7fa2-e953-475c-abde-f016e4f7b61a&displaylang=en).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use Managed DirectX, because its a death project and hasn't been updated since 2007. You should consider port you project to [XNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA) or [SlimDX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SlimDX)